# Wordpress - file upload form in page - empty $_FILES array

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to create a simple fileupload form in my custom Wordpress template:

```
<form action="<?php echo $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On submit, the `$_FILES` array is empty.

I think the problem is in the `action`, as the url that is generated is the nice URL, instead of `http://domain.com/somepost.php`

What should I put into the `action`, so I get the `$_FILES`?

Comment: Just blank your action and you get $_FILES ARRAY your same page if you form is submitted..

Comment: When I leave the `action` blank, for some reason I get empty `$_FILES` array...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
            else{
                    echo $_FILES['file']["name"]; //  your file name
            }
       }
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>
```